# Assign value to combination of two column values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for an easier way to assign a unique value to a combination of **string values** from two columns, where:

- (colA=2 and colB=4) and (colA=4 and colB=2) are given the same ID
- (colA=1 and colB=1) can't happen
- colA and colB are strings

Here is a minimal example of a solution that would work **if** colA and colB where numerics:

```
set.seed(3)
a <- sample(1:5, 20, replace = T) 
b <- sample(1:5, 20, replace = T) 

df<- data.frame(a, b)

library(dplyr)

df<- df %>% 
      filter(a!=b) %>% 
      mutate(abCombination = a*b) %>%
      arrange(abCombination)

df$abFactor <- factor(df$abCombination, labels = c("combination 1", "combination 2",
                                                   "combination 3", "combination 4",
                                                   "combination 5", "combination 6",
                                                   "combination 7"))
```

I feel that this is an easy task but can't think of:

1. solution working with strings
2. more elegant (concise) way to code it.

Comment: How does the multiplication works if both are not numeric,  Do you need `df %>% filter(a != b) %>% mutate(abCombination = sprintf('%s %s', pmin(a, b), pmax(a, b))) %>% arrange(abCombination) %>% mutate(abFactor = factor(abCombination, levels = unique(abCombination), labels = paste('Combination', seq_len(n_distinct(abCombination)))
 )
 )`

Comment: Multiplying doesn't guarantee your `abCombination` column will be unique. This is a result of the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithemetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). E.g 15 * 5 = 25 *3, but you would likely want these two combinations to be different. Unless of course you can guarantee that columns a and b will both contain only prime numbers (which you don't by including 4 in column a).

Comment: @ akrun for `a <- sample(letters, 20, TRUE)` it doesn't work. Do I miss something basic here?

Comment: @JosephWood good point. I didn't think about that. My real data example has only 5 levels of disctinct values so I guess there is no problem. But still - I'd happily use any kind of a general solution

Comment: I think you meant to post your comment on @akrun's answer.  I think it does work. You need to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` during creation of the the df. E.g. `df<- data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors = F)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that we are looking for a more general approach that works on both `numeric/non-numeric`, one option is to use the `pmin/pmax` to `paste` the elements and then do the `factor`

```
df %>% 
   filter(a != b) %>%
   mutate(abCombination = sprintf('%s %s', pmin(a, b), pmax(a, b))) %>% 
   arrange(abCombination) %>% 
   mutate(abFactor = factor(abCombination, levels = unique(abCombination), 
        labels = paste('Combination', seq_len(n_distinct(abCombination))) ))
```

Comment: great! Works as I wanted. Thank you.